# How to create a variable in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

So, I want to create a variable for the purposes of updating it in one place and have it change everywhere where it is referenced on the sheet.

For example. I want to associate a number with a day of the week.

- 01 = Sunday
- 02 = Monday
- ... etc.

Everywhere on the sheet that says Sunday, I want the number that is associated with Sunday to be displayed.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I just found an even simpler way to do what I want to do. I don't need no variable I just need to use this formula =CONCATENATE(A1), Assuming A1 contains Sunday in the cell. All I have to do is apply that formula anywhere I want Sunday to appear on the sheet. If I update A1 to Monday, that day will automatically update everywhere where the CONCATENATE formula is applied. Awesome.

Comment: You only need `CONCATENATE()` if you want to join multiple strings together like `CONCATENATE(A1, B1)`. If you just have the one cell, you can just do `=A1`.